# Wordpress How to get value from get_results function

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to get value from return object by WordPress `get_results` function  but no success with it

Sample code

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SUM(view) as dviews FROM view_count WHERE post_id = '$pid'");

echo $myrows->dviews;   // echo nothing
```

so any idea how to get the integer return as `dviews` from it.

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($myrows)`? The result may be an array. You might also try using `get_var` if you only need one value https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First of all if you want to get only one record then use `get_row()`
>   instead of `get_results()` because it will fetch all the data retrieved
>   by SQL query.

For single record

```
$result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT SUM(view) as dviews FROM view_count WHERE post_id = '$pid'");
echo $result->dviews;
```

For multiple records

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SUM(view) as dviews FROM view_count WHERE post_id = '$pid'");
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    echo $result->dviews;
}
```

Please Note: *If you have a table prefix the use `$wpdb->prefix` to get the correct table name.*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
foreach( $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SUM(view) as dviews FROM view_count WHERE post_id = '".$pid."';") as $key => $row) {
    // each column in your row will be accessible like this
        echo $row->column_name;
    }
```

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SUM(view) as dviews FROM view_count WHERE post_id =".$pid."");
foreach($myrows as $item)
{
echo $item->dviews;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add the prefix of your table and declare $wpdb as global variable as well in your query. I have modified your query as :

```
global $wpdb;
$myrows = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT SUM(view) as {prefix}dviews FROM view_count WHERE post_id = '$pid'");

echo $myrows[0]->dviews;
```